# Django. Make thumbs pictures

Tags: django, image

Any simple way to make thumb pictures automaticaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically it..
But here's a good snippet that uses the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to do what you want:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/224/

I've been using it on my app and I have no complaints so far!

Answer (score 2):

Use [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) which provides you some simple but [powerful template tags](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#template-examples) as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/), you can resize any photo on the fly and cache the result for next requests